# Get uri of CPT archive page

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type which uses an archive page and a slug

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'news'), 
'has_archive' => true
```

I am using a PHP form on one page which I want to post to `/news/` each time. I want a proper way to return the uri of this archive page `(www.mysite.com/news/)` from other pages. I don't mind doing round about manipulation to get the 'news' sub-string, I just want to eliminate 'magic variables' in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the `get_post_type_archive_link` function. As you declined to provide the name of your post type ( but you did provide its URL slug ), I cannot provide a full example, however, it would be something similar to this:

```
$link = get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type );
echo '<a href="'.$link.'">View Archive</a>';
```